# What is the right way to ask for contemporary information of an old subject on SO?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Today I wanted to learn about the contemporary status of the obfuscation of mail addresses on web pages.

I have seen that this is an old subject, asked a couple of years ago here on Stack Overflow. So I have written a new question and referred to the old ones.

The question got close flags for not belonging to Stack Overflow, and a recommendation to put it on Webmasters.

So I moved the question to Webmasters.

There, it was put on hold, with the recommendation that the right way to get information on an old question on Stack Overflow was to set a bounty on the old questions. But to me, this doesn't seem appropriate.

I would like to learn how to ask this question the right way on the right site. It is a question that clearly "continues" old questions, but it has so long been since that it deserves to become a new question. Can you give me some hints how to proceed?

---

The old questions mentioned:

- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748780/best-way-to-obfuscate-an-e-mail-address-on-a-website): April 2009
- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098408/is-it-worth-obfuscating-email-addresses-on-the-web-these-days): November 2010
- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184555/is-it-still-worth-obfuscating-email-addresses-to-prevent-harvesting): November 2010

My question:

[image: Question]

Comment: Is there a need to ask a question when there are blogs about it? http://techblog.tilllate.com/2008/07/20/ten-methods-to-obfuscate-e-mail-addresses-compared/ BTW, you can do your own research...

Comment: @Braiam, you don't understand my question. I am not asking how to obfuscate mail addresses, and if I would, I would not do "research" with a source from 2008. I am asking about today's need of obfuscation in consideration of new technology and spam filters, seen by people with more experience and a wider horizon than I have. Maybe you have?

Comment: No. And the fact that it needs a "refresh" doesn't mean that it makes a good question for SO. Remember, mail obfuscation isn't a task unique to programming environments.

Comment: Your beef is with WebMasters, really rather best to use their meta.  Where did you hear that before :)  You would perhaps have been better off if that old off-topic Q+A was deleted or migrated, very hard to do unfortunately.

Comment: @Braiam for literally every single question about open source, there is the source out there. Why don't we just all do our research and stop asking questions?  *facepalm*    —   Peter: just use your email address, it will show up somewhere some day in a readable format anyway. GMail is amazing at spam filtering. And for the flagging, this is not a programming question, nor will there be a simple fact based answer, so Quora might be a better fit?

Comment: Minor thing: "a couple of years ago" != 2010; "a couple of years ago" == 2014 (you might get away with late 2013). :)

Comment: @mmlac, thank you for the hint for Quora. That's interesting, will have a look; knowing about it seems to belong to a good educational background.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, well I'm not native :-D thanks for the hint. "Years ago", "Some / several years ago" would be the better choice. Or, "A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away..."

Answer (score 26):

Since I want do suggest an other thing, I do not want to edit my [orignal answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318491/2441442) (Because Meta Votes are for a single suggestion imho).

If you don't want to open a bounty (or can not, because of reputation restriction) you should ask yourself:

**Why do the old answers not work for you?**

Then you should ask a seperate question, with a clear problem statement. What is wrong with the existing Answers? Link to it as a reference.

**Wrong:**

> What is the best method to get foo in 2016

**Right**

> I need to get foo correct in current days. There are existing answers
>   [here](http://example.com), [here](http://example.com) and
>   [here](http://example.com).
>
> My problem is, I can not get foo because of bar and baz, which is not adressed in the original questions.
>
> How can I get foo including bar and baz?

Comment: Thank you very much for you effort. You are suggesting to get more concrete and precise. I agree, my question could be improved in that line.

Comment: How does this help users who will continue to visit those old questions?  Creating a new question does not help them.

Comment: if they need to find a solution for foo including bar or baz, they will find. @cimmanon

Comment: But **this** question is *not* asking about getting a solution that includes bar or baz, it is about getting a modern answer for an old question.

Comment: Why is an old answer not modern? Maybe because `bar` was introduced to the topic. @cimmanon

Comment: @cimmanon sometimes the line between a "related" and "duplicated" question is the scope. If peter's question was in the same scope as the old, the old answer would suffice. But peter needs to put his problem (that cannot be solved by old answers) in a light that can convince the community that it is a different, but related question. That is scope, IMHO.

Comment: @Mindwin I've seen plenty of old questions dismissed as not being relevant because the answer is "no, that's not possible (sometimes with a workaround)".  The asker typically has this vain hope that things have changed or "none of the workarounds provided work for me (because I don't want to do those things, I only want to do the exact thing I asked about)"

Comment: I take from this answer that the answer to the question that was actually asked is: There is no way to get updated information on SO.  One must hope that people who have the updated information (as opposed to those _looking_ for it) will spend time looking up questions they _already_ know the answer to and will write new answers.

Comment: Technology is mostly timeless. If a solution does not work anymore, the technology most probably has changed or at least its api. This change is "bar" in above example @RyanLundy

Comment: Oh, absolutely.  Timeless.  If we have to change the way we do things, it must be that the old ways simply don't function anymore.  That's why even in 2018 we all travel by steam train and send our letters by Pony Express.  Those methods still work, so why change them?

Comment: I am talking about the technologie in question. If the question is how do I travel with a steam train, why should we answer: *Don't, please travel with hyperloop?*. In that specific example, the correct question would be more: *"I want to travel through the USA. I heard about steam train, but it is to slow for my usecase. How can I speed up the Steam train, or is there any good alternate way of solving this traveling problem?"* @RyanLundy

Comment: But even when the hyperloop is available, "How can I get from St Louis to California?" is going to be closed as a duplicate because there's already a question about that, with the answer being Amtrak, never mind that it's no longer the best answer.  The current state of affairs seems to assume that when the hyperloop opens, somebody will rush to update all those questions with "Hey, now you can take the hyperloop!" answers.  Or that people will give bounty to get better answers...which assumes they know that there _are_ better answers, in which case they probably already know the answers.

Comment: Yes, I agree, that will not happen, except for highly hot topics. The problem we have is, that the format of this site is not very good designed for it. If we would allow them, I imagine the flood of informations: *"How do do x in 2018/19/20/21/22 ..."*. Having one question which solves *x* in many different ways (with competing votes) is from the perspective of a developer who googled *x* better. I think in reality, we need to have some feature for requesting updated information. But I have no idea how this can be designed. But maybe someone comes up with a feature-request. @RyanLundy

Answer (score 9):

I would add a bounty on an old question, with some text like

> While the current answers have had good points for the year 2009, I am searching for a more up-to-date answer, that covers today's best practices.

You would need at least 75 reputation for this (credits to TylerH). [<s>I am not sure about, what new users can do.</s>](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318514/2441442)

Comment: It's worth noting this is viable only for users above a certain rep threshold. You can't set bounties until 75 reputation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint. I see clearer now how I could proceed with the "bounty way".

Answer (score 3):

**Summary**

As you know, a lot of questions in Stack Overflow are visible today for rather historical reasons. This doesn't mean that those are good questions. Some of them are even flagged that way. Over time, lots of them have become a burden, and it remains a challenge for the Stack Overflow Meta Processing how to deal with them.

It seems your question refers to some of this kind. In that case, it is difficult.

Maybe you think "obfuscating mail addresses" is a task that web front end programmers doubtlessly have to deal with. Maybe you, from your point of view, wish to explain your customer why you do it or why you don't it, and you wish to rely on best practice. However, it is controversial if it is a question valid for Stack Overflow.

Migrating a question to other sites has been turned out to be difficult sometimes. People on the other site will think you should choose other ways to ask on the original side.

Simply accept that certain (rare) questions cannot be asked in a suitable way, and go on trying to open some other doors. You'll find a way.

Comment: Other answers with a wider horizon are welcome :-)

Comment: Questions older than 6 months cannot be migrated using the standard migration path. They need manual intervention of at least a moderator, possibly even an SO employee. That's why they tend to hang around on the "wrong" site. Getting enough people to vote on very old questions is hard. That's why they tend to stay open, and don't get closed or deleted. The result is that questions which, according to changing scope of the site, have become off-topic retroactively, tend to stay around and stay open forever. There's really not much that can be done about it, even though it's a constant nuisance

Comment: … because they certainly give the impression that it's okay to ask such questions. For an extreme example of this problem, you can visit [programmer.se], which has had a rather drastic change of scope from the extremely broad "everything that's off-topic on SO" to "subjective questions about programming" (both of which were a disaster) to the very narrow "objective conceptual questions about software development and software design", yet there are still plenty of questions from the "anything goes" era that of course are used by askers as a justification for why their particular broad …

Comment: … subjective off-topic questions should be allowed.